# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property propTypes of function Settings(props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The prop types are working fine with normal react component but fails with Redux connected component.

Error details

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property propTypes of function Settings(props)

Complete error details

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property propTypes of function Settings(props) {
>       _classCallCheck(this, Settings);

```
var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(thi...<omitted>... } which has only a getter
at Object.eval (Settings.js?384b:533)
at eval (Settings.js:509)
at Object../src/Navigation/Components/Settings.js (main.b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a.js?b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a:14403)
at __webpack_require__ (main.b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a.js?b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a:725)
at fn (main.b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a.js?b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a:102)
at eval (routes.js?5665:15)
at Object../src/routes.js (main.b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a.js?b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a:14763)
at __webpack_require__ (main.b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a.js?b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a:725)
at fn (main.b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a.js?b2f70c3c5e2d43b8884a:102)
at eval (index.js?b635:2)
```

I am using prop-types v15, react v16, react-redux v3 lib's.

Settings.js Component:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Settings extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

static get propTypes() {
    return {
      loginId:React.PropTypes.string,
      loading: React.PropTypes.bool,  
      updateEmail: React.PropTypes.func
    }
  }

render(){
   return(
      <div>{this.props.text}</div>
   )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   let text = "Hello Settings";
   return {
      text
   }
}

Settings.propTypes = {
    loginId: PropTypes.string,
    loading: PropTypes.bool
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Settings);
```

Comment: Maybe, that's due to mapStateToProps? You return undefined in that function.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. It fails even after returning text in mapStateToProps. Updated my code.

Comment: Sorry It was my mistake. I haven't removed the old static get propTypes and thats why it was failing. The issue got resolved After removing static get propTypes. Sorry for providing less Information. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

mapStateToProps is meant to send variables from the redux store to the react component.

But you are using it to just set a prop.

But, in line with the comment from Bartek, you could try this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        text: "hello settings"
    }
}
```

The way you should use mapStateToProps is more like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        text: state.text
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joey. I tried your solution but its giving me the same error

Comment: Oh it looks like your missing a closing parenthesis on your class `}`

Comment: Sorry I typed code manually. I am having same issue with proper component

Comment: I have added complete error details. Can you please check once

Comment: Have you wrapped the App in a <Provider>?
All I can think is that you are not using `connect` for its intended purpose. Why don't you set that text message in your reducer initial state?

Comment: Sorry It was my mistake. I haven't removed the old static get propTypes and thats why it was failing. The issue got resolved After removing static get propTypes. Sorry for providing less Information. Thanks for your time.